# lock Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, thread-safety, currentuiculture

I've a method that runs an action with a specific CurrentUICulture and at the end it rolls back to the original CurrentUICulture. Here's the snippet

```
    private static void ExecuteInLanguage(string language, Action action)
    {
        var current = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        try
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
            action();
        }
        finally
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = current;
        }
    }
```

CurrentUICulture is temporary changed in different parts of my project.

The problem is that sometimes "action()" does not run with the temporary setted CurrentUICulture passed to "ExecuteInLanguage", but with other languages, probably because CurrentUICulture is changed in the same time somewhere else.

Could using "lock" be the correct solution to avoid the described?

```
    private static void ExecuteInLanguage(string language, Action action)
    {
        var current = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        try
        {
            lock (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture)
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
                action();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = current;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, lock won't help here. However, if `action` completely runs on the same thread (no async or anything like that), then the only place something can change ui culture is inside `action` itself.

Comment: Thank you @Evk. UI culture does not change into action, but it is set in other parts of the project, within other methods.

Comment: But if action is sequential and always runs in the same thread, then nothing can change ui culture (of thread where action executes) while it executes using code in question.

Comment: What if CurrentUICulture is changed in different threads? Could this be the point?

Comment: You are setting Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, so culture of current thread. Different thread cultures cannot affect it.

Comment: This appears to be a problem of using a *global* setting to try to fix a *local* problem. The fix is to pass a culture explicitly to `action`.